# Setting up a modular project in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm coming from the Visual Studio world of solutions, where each solution can consist of multiple projects that can refer to each other.

What I want to do is create a modular Android project in Android Studio such that all my code doesn't live in one huge app project. However, it seems terribly difficult to do this, so much so that I am sure I am doing something wrong.

I created a blank project called `MyProject`. This creates a project with the name `MyProject` and a package `com.sohum.myproject`. There is a single `app` project contained within containing no source files.

I now want to add another module under the same namespace (e.g. `com.sohum.myproject.library1`). However, it seems when I try to add a new module via the menu, I can only do so into a `com.sohum.library1` project. How do I get it to use the same package as the project?

My end goal is to have all my modules under the `com.sohum.myproject` package, referencing each other. For example:

`com.sohum.myproject.application` will be the entry point. It might depend on `com.sohum.myproject.library1` and `com.sohum.myproject.someotherlibrary`. And I would like to see all of these modules when I open the MyProject file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click File > New > New Module. Then choose Android Library and enter the details.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to set up the project in a subpackage when creating it.

For example, create a project `MyProject` in a root directory. Call the application `Application` and rename the package to be `com.sohum.myproject.app` instead of just `com.sohum.myproject`. Now any new modules created will be added below the `com.sohum.myproject` package space.